# Listview in TabActivity hide layout

Tags: android, listview, tabactivity

This is the context: I have a TabActivity with three tabs,|Contacts|History|Caller| in the tab on contacts, I have another TabActivity. In this TacActvity I have set the tabwidget invisible and I use a personal layout on the top to change among tabs: |Server|Agenda|Directory| basically i use the onClick event to setCurrentTab in the TabHost. If I set a normal Activity on a TabContent its OK, the problem is when I set a ListActivity with a ListView as the TabContent,in that case the lisview hide the 3 buttons on the on the top, and I can no longer interact with those buttons. As you can see on the [image](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3340490/Captura.PNG) 
Any ideas of why or how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Is the android:layout_height set to fill_parent for the ListActivity?
Changing it to wrap_content might help